# Scala random number in a string

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

```
val scn = scenario("newUser")
    .exec(http("request_0")
        .get("/wordpress/?page_id=83")
        .headers(headers_0))
    .pause(1)
    .exec(http("request_1")
        .post("/wordpress/?page_id=83")
        .headers(headers_1)
        .body(RawFileBody("new_user_request_0001.txt")))

setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(100))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

My question is the following... I have to load 100 text files with structure like that in the example ("new_user_request_0001.txt"), using numbers between 0 to 100 randomly. How can I do? Thank you all

Comment: If you have to load 100 files with values of 0 to 100 randomly - does that mean you're just looking for a random _sorting_ of the files (i.e. each value in [0, 100) should be used exactly once), or do you want to select the values randomly so that some might repeat themselves?

Comment: The range "0 to 100" contains 101 numbers, not hundred... But I assume these are minor details.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. You can use [Random.shuffle](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/util/Random.html#shuffle%5BT,CC%5BX%5D%3C:TraversableOnce%5BX%5D%5D(CC%5BT%5D)(CanBuildFrom%5BCC%5BT%5D,T,CC%5BT%5D%5D):CC%5BT%5D)

```
scala.util.Random.shuffle(0 to 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `uniformRandomSwitch`, generate a sequence of 100 `ChainBuilders`, and then use the `(...): _*` syntax to unpack it as an argument to a vararg-method:

```
val scn = scenario("newUser")
    .exec(http("request_0")
        .get("/wordpress/?page_id=83")
        .headers(headers_0))
    .pause(1)
    .uniformRandomSwitch(
        ((0 until 100).map{ idx =>
          http("request_1")
          .post("/wordpress/?page_id=83")
          .headers(headers_1)
          .body(RawFileBody(s"new_user_request_0${idx}.txt")))
        }): _*
    )
```

The `s" ...  ${idx} ..."` syntax injects the `idx` argument passed by `map` into the string.